# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

Evaluate $$L=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}} \tag{1}$$

I have used L Hopital's  Rule we get

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} 2\frac{ \sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}} \sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$$

$\implies$

$$L=2 \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ \sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{x}$$  and from $(1)$ we get

$$L=\frac{2}{L}$$

$$L=\sqrt{2}$$

is this correct appraoach?

Comment: your result is right

Comment: In case you're interested in another approach, you could square the thing, then multiply top and bottom by the conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The result is not right, as the limit doesn't exist at all.

Comment: I believe that you still need to specify whether you are approaching $0$ from the left or right; this will result in a sign change, depending on your choice.

Comment: $$x\to 0^+ ,l=\sqrt 2 \\x\to 0^- ,l=-\sqrt 2$$

Comment: You don't know if the original limit exists or not and you are also not aware whether the limit of expression obtained after L'Hospital's Rule exists or not. Then you can not arrive at the equation $L = 2/L$. As pointed out in other comments $x \to 0^{+}$ and $x \to 0^{-}$ give different limits, but your approach fails even if we use it to get one-sided limits because we are not aware of existence of the limit before L'Hospital and after L'Hospital. The limit is an algebraic one and most easily handled by mul/div with $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}$.

Answer (score 7):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\stackrel{x\mapsto\sin\theta}{=}\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}}=\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{2}\left|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right|}\stackrel{\theta\mapsto2\varphi}{=}\sqrt{2}\lim_{\varphi\to 0}\frac{\cos\varphi\sin\varphi}{\left|\sin\varphi\right|} $$
clearly does not exist, but $\lim_{x\to 0^{\pm}}(\ldots)=\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Love your solution! It's so clever. I think that $\sqrt{1-x^2}=^{x\mapsto\sin(\theta)}|\cos(\theta)|$, right?

Comment: Never mind... If $\theta\in(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ then $\cos(\theta)>0$

Comment: @Ixion: there is no need of the absolute value in such a case. $x\to 0$ leads to $\theta\to 0$, hence $\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=\cos\theta$ since the LHS is non-negative.

Answer (score 4):

Your result is wrong, sorry: the limit doesn't exist.

If you want to consider the limit from the right, you can use $x=\sqrt{x^2}$, for $x>0$, and write it as
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}=
\lim_{x\to0^+}\sqrt{\frac{x^2(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}{1-(1-x^2)}}=
\lim_{x\to0^+}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sqrt{2}
$$
For the limit from the left, you have to take into account that $x=-\sqrt{x^2}$ for $x<0$, so you have
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}-\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}=-\sqrt{2}
$$
with the same computations as above.

Your argument that $L=2/L$ just shows that *if the limit $L$ exists* then $L^2=2$, but tells you nothing about the existence.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not correct.  If the limit existed, then

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-(-x)^2}}}=-L\\\implies L=0$$

What you have found was

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac x{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}=\sqrt2$$

So in fact, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: yes i agree with that thanks

Comment: Sorry, looks like I posted the same answer. I should have read more closely before posting. +1 for you.

Comment: @MPW Lol, no problem I guess

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, if the limit exists it must be zero (because $x\to 0$ is equivalent to $(-x)\to 0$, so you could replace $x$ by $-x$ and obtain the opposite result, which would have to equal the original result and so be zero). So, in fact, you have shown that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: 
$$L=\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac{sgn(x) \sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}=$$
$$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} sgn(x) \sqrt{\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}} =(LR)= $$
$$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} sgn(x) \sqrt{\lim_\limits{x\to 0} 2\sqrt{1-x^2}}=$$
$$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} sgn(x) \sqrt{2}.$$
Hence, the limit exists if $x$ approaches $0$ from left or right, otherwise it does not exist.

Comment: Typing via smartphone is quite challenging.

Answer (score 0):

There is a right limit and a left limit and they are different, which means that the limit doesn't exist because when it exists it is unique.

Let substitute $1-x^2=w^2$

Suppose $x>0$ we have $x=\sqrt{1-w^2}$ and the limit becomes

$$\lim_{w\to 1} \, \dfrac{\sqrt{1-w^2}}{\sqrt{1-w}}=\lim_{w\to 1} \, \frac{\sqrt{1-w} \sqrt{w+1}}{\sqrt{1-w}}=\lim_{w\to 1} \,\sqrt{w+1}= \sqrt{2}$$

If $x<0$ then we have $x=-\sqrt{1-w^2}$

And the previous limit gives $- \sqrt{2}$

Hope this helps